# API response: Access member with hyphen in name

Tags: php, api

I am in an absurd situation. I am using an API who returns to me

```
[winner-id] => 15404899
```

The way I select elements from the API's return is:

```
$matches->returnElement;
```

The problem is that I can't get winner-id's value cause when I type

```
$matches->winner-id;
```

It's invalid variable because of the (-) sign. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Show the code where your'e getting `$matches`.

Comment: Solved, thanks for passing by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$matches->{'winner-id'};
```

Comment: It has 15 minute wait time from the question was started. I had to wait them.